# При считывании из файла в конец строки записывается мусор

Tags: c++, файлы, fstream

```
int size; char *fileData;
ifstream file("big.txt");
file.seekg(0, ios::end);
size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

fileData = new char [size];

file.read(fileData,size);
file.close();
cout << fileData << endl;
```

Почему в `fileData` в конец строки записывается мусор (значение `size` вычисляется верно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
ifstream file("big.txt",ios::binary);
...
fileData = new char [size+1];
file.read(fileData,size);
fileData[size]=0;
```

Comment: Мусор пропал, но теперь добавляет HHHH вместо него

Comment: Ну так откройте файл как бинарный...

Comment: зачем, это же текстовый файл?

Comment: Затем, что раз он текстовый, у вас `\n\r` будет преобразовываться в **ОДИН** символ, а при `tellg` - считаться за два. Разница мусором и заполнится. Я думал, вы в Linux'е каком работаете, там символ один, но, похоже, вы в Windows, а тут это важно.